# Building OpenCV Native Camera Wrapper

Tags: android, opencv

I want to use OpenCV's native camera on an Android 4.4.2 device using Qualcomm's version of Android for MSM platforms. Based on the only comment on [this OpenCV bug report](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3995), recompiling the native camera wrapper against the built android source tree works.

The instructions for building the wrapper [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk) seem outdated since the commands don't appear to match the project layout (eg: it has the command cd opencv/android when the current project is opencv/platform/android). I'm having difficulty figuring out how to build it.

At the moment, I have ANDROID_STUB_ROOT set to the correct directory and I copied the output of compilation to ANDROID_STUB_ROOT/4.4.0/bin_arm since the scripts appeared to expect it there. After some fiddling, cmake_android_all_cameras.py now completes cmake, but I get the error:

make: *** No rule to make target `native_camera_r4.4.0'.  Stop.

Looking further up in the log I see

AndroidNativeCamera:         YES, use prebuilt libraries

Which seems to be the culprit. I don't understand why "cmake_android_all_cameras.py" results in a makefile that can't build any cameras.

If there a detailed up-to-date, I would appreciate the link. Otherwise, can you point me in the right direction? More specific questions would be:

1. What are the requirements for the layout of the android source/build?
2. What environment variables need to be set?
3. What scripts need to be run from what directories in what order to produce a native camera library?

[Here is the full build log](http://pastebin.com/xCDEx1QD).